# Solve equations with integral in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find roots of x (X[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hjts.gif) in code) and y (X[2] in code) for two equations as follows

[Integral Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Hjts.gif)

I use function multiroot in R package rootSolve:

```
m<-0.01 
r<- 0.5
c<- 0.01006885

eq.sol<-function(x,para)
{
  m<-para[1]
  r<-para[2]
  c<-para[3]
  inteq1<-function(b)
  {
   x[1]*exp(-x[1]*b)/(b+x[2])
  }
  inteq2<-function(b)
  {
   x[1]*exp(-x[1]*b)/(b+x[2])^2 
  }
  F1<-integrate(inteq1, 0, Inf)$value-m*c*(1-r)/(c+m*r)
  F2<-integrate(inteq2, 0, Inf)$value-m^2*c*(1-r)^2/(c+m*r)
  c(F1=F1, F2=F2)
}

find.para<-multiroot(eq.sol, start = c(0.05,1), para = c(m, r, c), positive = TRUE)
```

where m, r and c are constants. Two variables are expected to be positive. However, it returns following errors:

```
diagonal element is zero 
[1] 2
Warning messages:
1: In stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) :
  error during factorisation of matrix (dgefa);         singular matrix
2: In stode(y, times, func, parms = parms, ...) : steady-state not reached
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks for Lyngbakr's solution. It seems a good initial guess is necessary in this case. However, if inserting this function in another function and randomly drawing c from some distribution, say U(0.005, 0.05), I cannot make it work for all samples of c. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Integrating wrt `x` in the pictures, I assume?

Comment: FYI: `multiroot` takes an argument called `parms` not `para`.

Comment: @Therkel In fact, integrating wrt b.

Comment: Regarding your edit: my suggestion is that your two functions are volatile around the choice of `c`. This influences the numerical approximations quite a lot. You do not specify what you mean by *"cannot make it work"*. You can perhaps play around with the following: `set.seed(1); c <- c(0.005,runif(10,0.005,0.05),0.05); sapply(c, function(c){ out = multiroot(eq.sol, start = c(x = 1e-3, y = 1e-3), parms = c(m, r, c), positive = TRUE, maxiter = 500,useFortran = TRUE); c(c = c,out$root,iter = out$iter) })
`
Of course, insert appropriate linebreaks for readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try different initial guesses. For example,

```
find.para<-multiroot(eq.sol, start = c(1e-3, 1e-3), parms = c(phi, r, c), positive = TRUE)
```

gives,

```
$root
[1]  0.002437481 98.082693040

$f.root
           F1            F2 
-2.844821e-09 -5.135857e-12 

$iter
[1] 21

$estim.precis
[1] 1.424978e-09
```

Comment: Thank you! So, it seems a good initial guess is necessary. If I wanna insert this function in another function and randomly sample c from some distribution, I guess it's difficult for me to make multiroot work for each random sample c. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: @ChenChen I don't know of any *a priori* way of choosing good initial guesses. Is it guaranteed that there will only be one root for each variable? One approach may be to catch errors and retry with other (random?) initial conditions until you get a good result.

Comment: Although there might be multiple roots, I just need to pick one of them. I think tryCatch is definitely a good idea. Cannot agree any more. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChenChen Multiple roots may be tricky. My first thought is to choose random initial guesses for each random `c`. Sort of a nested sampling scheme. This way you are more likely to get a good result as well as multiple roots. But, as the documentation for `multiroot` states, there are no guarantees. Plus, this may be time consuming. ^shrug^